# UIView transition problem from bottom to up

Tags: swift, uiview, swift4.2, uiviewanimationtransition

In my application I want to animate a view from bottom to up in `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. So far I have done this way to transit the view from bottom but in different device it is showing different UI. UIView transition is working but view is not fully transitioning from bottom expect iPhone XS. So far I have done these two ways :

**First Step**:

```
    let currentFrame = self.animationVIew.frame
    self.animationVIew.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height, width: currentFrame.size.width, height: currentFrame.size.height)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        self.animationVIew.frame = currentFrame
        self.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
```

**Second Step**:

```
UIView.transition(with: animationVIew,
                      duration: 0.5,
                      options: [.transitionFlipFromBottom],
                      animations: {

    },
    completion: nil)
```

But for both way I am facing same problem. No luck!!

[image: First image iPhone 6 Plus Second image iPhone XR and Third iPhone XS]

Comment: Show your code _in context_. A lot depends on where the code runs. For example if you’re getting the frame in `viewDidLoad` you are going to get the wrong answer most of the time.

Comment: I am writing this code at `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was my mistake I did not think in proper way to solve it.Anyway if anyone face similar kind of problem then may be this answer will help them. I have just changed the current `autolayout` to fix this issue.This problem was happening because of constraint between `animationView` and `topView`. The distance constraint between these two view was fixed, That is why when animation was happening it was resizing the `animationView` to adjust the constraints.So my solution was making the animation view height constraint fixed and have changed the priority `required` to `low` of distance constraint between `animationView` and `topView` in storyboard

Comment: Good but since that information was not in the question it is hardly a fair answer.

Comment: Ok next time I will try to add more detail about the problem.